# How to remove specific lines from all files?

Tags: linux, sed

I want to delete all lines begin with 'sometext' from many files:

```
find . -name "*.php"|xargs -I {} sed -e '/^sometext/d' {}
```

But this put me output to console. How to modify this files directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -i option of sed:

```
 sed -i -e '/^sometext/d' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Tell sed to modify the files "in place":

```
find . -name "*.php" | xargs sed -i '' -e '/^sometext/d'
```

Note that the blank `''` after `-i` is required, otherwise a new copy with a default suffix will be created.

Also note the pruning if your unnecessary `-I` in `xaegs`

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with `exec`:

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec sed -i '/^sometext/d' {} \;
```